# How Can I Make a Capturing Group Optional using Ruby's 'scan' Method?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I have a regex like this:

```
(.*?)("DisplayName":.*?)(,)(.*?"Groups":?)?(\[.*?\])?(,)(.*?"Phones":)?(\[.*?\])?(.*?\},)?
```

with which I want to process a string like this:

> {"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"Moe Larry","Emails":[{"Address":"moelarry@gmail.com","Primary":true,"Type":{"Id":"HOME"}}],"FullName":{"FamilyName":"Larry","GivenName":"Moe","Unstructured":"Moe Larry"},"Groups":[{"id":"^Mine"}],"Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"Moe Larry","Phones":[{"Number":"555-999-6661","Type":{"Id":"MOBILE"}}],"ProfileLink":""},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"stoogesarefunny","Emails":[{"Address":"stoogesarefunny","Primary":true}],"EvergreenPhoto":"/photos/private/adflk;jsd394u75430o8752380974321jtkasdljf8937489213749832654","Id":"834754hthbf83744823f","MailsSent":0},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"stoogesarefunny@gmail.com","Emails":[{"Address":"stoogesarefunny@gmail.com","Primary":true}],"EvergreenPhoto":"/photos/private/asdfAJDKLJSFIOEJHLTHSJKLDF234987s897KJHSDFKJHDF89273473ASLKJDLSKJIFEIH","Id":"834754hthbf83744823f","MailsSent":0,"ProfileLink":"https://profiles.google.com/stoogesarefunny"},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"Shemp","FullName":{"GivenName":"Shemp","Unstructured":"Shemp"},"Groups":[{"id":"^Mine"}],"Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"Shemp","Phones":[{"Number":"+15553085671","Type":{"Id":"OTHER"}}]},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"ClownFace","FullName":{"GivenName":"ClownFace","Unstructured":"ClownFace"},"Groups":[{"id":"^Mine"}],"Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"ClownFace","Phones":[{"Number":"+15556064040","Type":{"Id":"OTHER"}}]},

It's really effing ugly, I know. I wish I could find an xml feed, but that's not an option right now.

All I care about are DisplayName, Groups, and Phones. I need to extract and save them in an array of arrays. The capturing groups for Groups and Phones need to be optional because not all contacts have them. However, my regex gives me:

```
Result 1

1. {"Affinity":20,
2. "DisplayName":"Moe Larry"
3. ,
4. "Emails":[{"Address":"moelarry@gmail.com","Primary":true,"Type":{"Id":"HOME"}}],"FullName":{"FamilyName":"Larry","GivenName":"Moe","Unstructured":"Moe Larry"},"Groups":
5. [{"id":"^Mine"}]
6. ,
7. "Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"Moe Larry","Phones":
8. [{"Number":"555-999-6661","Type":{"Id":"MOBILE"}}]
9. ,"ProfileLink":""},

Result 2

1. {"Affinity":20,
2. "DisplayName":"stoogesarefunny"
3. ,
4. "Emails":[{"Address":"stoogesarefunny","Primary":true}],"EvergreenPhoto":"/photos/private/adflk;jsd394u75430o8752380974321jtkasdljf8937489213749832654","Id":"834754hthbf83744823f","MailsSent":0},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"stoogesarefunny@gmail.com","Emails":[{"Address":"stoogesarefunny@gmail.com","Primary":true}],"EvergreenPhoto":"/photos/private/asdfAJDKLJSFIOEJHLTHSJKLDF234987s897KJHSDFKJHDF89273473ASLKJDLSKJIFEIH","Id":"834754hthbf83744823f","MailsSent":0,"ProfileLink":"https://profiles.google.com/stoogesarefunny"},{"Affinity":20,"DisplayName":"Shemp","FullName":{"GivenName":"Shemp","Unstructured":"Shemp"},"Groups":
5. [{"id":"^Mine"}]
6. ,
7. "Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"Shemp","Phones":
8. [{"Number":"+15553085671","Type":{"Id":"OTHER"}}]
9. },

Result 3

1. {"Affinity":20,
2. "DisplayName":"ClownFace"
3. ,
4. "FullName":{"GivenName":"ClownFace","Unstructured":"ClownFace"},"Groups":
5. [{"id":"^Mine"}]
6. ,
7. "Id":"1234567890","MailsSent":0,"Name":"ClownFace","Phones":
8. [{"Number":"+15556064040","Type":{"Id":"OTHER"}}]
9. },
```

Clearly, all of Shemp's contact data is being subsumed into stoogesarefunny@gmail.com's data because my regex continues chomping away until it gets to Shemps Group instead of stopping before his Display Name and starting over. Help?

P.S.: No, I don't plan to save all these groups, ultimately, it's just so I can study what is going on.

Comment: The string you have is JSON. Why not use JSON tools to process it?

Comment: Your JSON sample isn't correct either. If you give us valid data we can give you a better answer. Reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to show what you are working with.

Comment: @Tomalak: because i didn't know it was JSON.  i'm a sysadmin forced into doing some coding.

Answer (score 6):

Your input looks like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for which there are already parsers for Ruby:

```
gem install json
```

Then in ruby:

```
data = JSON.parse(string)
```

You can then access `data` directly as a hash object, for example:

```
data = '
  {"Affinity":20,
    "DisplayName":"Moe Larry",
    "Emails":[{"Address":"moelarry@gmail.com","Primary":true,"Type":{"Id":"HOME"}}],
    "FullName":{"FamilyName":"Larry","GivenName":"Moe","Unstructured":"Moe Larry"},
    "Groups":[{"id":"^Mine"}],
    "Id":"1234567890",
    "MailsSent":0,
    "Name":"Moe Larry",
    "Phones":[{"Number":"555-999-6661","Type":{"Id":"MOBILE"}}],
    "ProfileLink":""
  }
'

require 'json'
user = JSON.parse(data)
user.class                    # => Hash
user.keys                     # => ["Affinity", "DisplayName", "Emails", "FullName", "Groups", "Id", "MailsSent", "Name", "Phones", "ProfileLink"]
user['Affinity']              # => 20
user['DisplayName']           # => "Moe Larry"
user['Emails']                # => [{"Address"=>"moelarry@gmail.com", "Primary"=>true, "Type"=>{"Id"=>"HOME"}}]
user['Emails'].class          # => Array
user['Emails'][0]             # => {"Address"=>"moelarry@gmail.com", "Primary"=>true, "Type"=>{"Id"=>"HOME"}}
user['Emails'][0]['Address']  # => "moelarry@gmail.com"
```